# XSS protection header for firefox

Tags: xss, nginx

I have enabled XSS protection in server using nginx with below header. But After long research google chrome, IE 10 & above and safari supports that but Firefox doesnt support

> add_header X-XSS-Protection: "1; mode=block";

For eg: when i try below url in IE, chrome and safari it blocks

> `https://xyz.com/test"><img src%3Dx onerror%3Dalert("xss")></`

But Firefox executes alert. Please help me to fix for Mozilla FF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox doesn't support the `X-XSS-Protection` header as you can see in [this compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-XSS-Protection#Browser_compatibility).

If you want similar protection against reflected XSS as a Firefox user, you can use the [NoScript addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/). It has an [anti-XSS feature](https://noscript.net/features#xss) that can similarly warn you if it identifies script code in the URL.

You should only see the header as a last line of defense that doesn't replace proper output escaping and the usual [anti-XSS measures](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). Many websites like Facebook don't enable the header at all because it can occasionally [cause security problems](http://blog.innerht.ml/the-misunderstood-x-xss-protection/) itself.

On the server side you can also deploy a [web application firewall](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Web_Application_Firewall) that may attempt to block XSS attempts. But your first security measure should be a secure application that properly filters output itself.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But how can do through server or on my coding (PHP). No script addon is plugin for firefox browser i can't inform all user to enable addon before using my site.

Comment: @satheesh I amended my answer. What is it exactly that you need? The correct way to tackle reflected XSS is filtering output. You may not want to rely on additional headers too much.

Comment: I'm using Drupal7 above issue given by security team on vulnerability. Its blocked in all browser except Firefox. can you help on any other way to fix security hole for Firefox.

Comment: @satheesh You need to find out what the exact vulnerability is and see if there is a patch available - or patch it yourself. Without details of the bug, it will be hard to help you fix it.